# When should I use distinct instances or shared instances across multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

The first way is this:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Apple a1 = new Apple();
        Apple a2 = new Apple();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a1, "First Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a2, "Second Thread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The second way is this:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Apple a = new Apple();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(a, "First Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(a, "Second Thread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The void `run()` method is in Apple class and I did not paste it here. 
Seems like in the first situation I created 2 Apple class objects and pass them respectively to `t1` and `t2`. While in the 2nd situation I pass  the same Apple class object to `t1` and `t2`. What's the real difference in terms of multi-threading? Could you suggest me which way is correct and recommended? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry spare my poor format editting here.... The page confuses me...

Comment: When writing your post, have a look at the preview that can be found just below the text box. That way, you can see if the formatting has worked correctly.

Comment: Doing it the first way solves one class of problem. Doing it the second way solves a different class of problem. What is the problem that you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If your `Apple` object is stateless then there is no difference.
But if it has some state and its `run()` method modifies it properties then you need to synchronize access to those properties (or make sure that those properties are thread-safe) of an `Apple` object.

What to prefer depends on your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

If `Apple` is an object which is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) then it may be okay (or indeed desirable) to share it between threads. If it's not thread-safe then by using it concurrently you are creating an opportunity for [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) and other difficult-to-diagnose bugs to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Difference depends a lot on implementation of `Apple` class, in 1 case this might be best option while in another it might be huge mistake.

If class `Apple` is immutable and just exposes some data or event better if it only has pure functions which depend only on their input parameters then using same instance is desired approach.

On the other hand if class isn't made to work with multiple threads then you will definitely run into [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) problems.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the `Apple` class really does. Let's look at a sample `Apple` class:

```
public class Apple implements Runnable{
    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void run(){
       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
           counter += i;
       }
       System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Now in the first way you get prints in the console which look like the following:

```
45 // first thread
45 // second thread
```

Though in the second way it will be pretty unpredictable because now both Threads are modifying the `counter` variable. It could at best look like this:

```
45 // first thread 
90 // second thread
```

But could also look like this:

```
51 // first thread
90 // second thread
```

In this simple example it is not a big issue. But when handling other tasks, which maybe modify files, accesses databases or anything that relies on deterministic behavior you'll get into big trouble.,